# Not able to parallel execute linux command in python using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have two files in my present working directory,

```
cwd:
    0.docx
    1.docx
```

---

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
import subprocess

def convert_to(source):
    args = [
        "soffice",
        "--headless",
        "--convert-to",
        "pdf:writer_pdf_Export",
        source,
    ]
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        args,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False,
    )
    return process.communicate()

pool = Pool()
print(pool.map(convert_to, ["0.docx", "1.docx"]))
```

Now, after executing the above code If I check my current working directory,

Here are the files I see,

```
cwd:
    0.docx
    1.docx
    1.pdf
```

Its only converting one file `(i.e., docx to pdf)` but the code is suppose to be executing both at once and convert both the files.

Please help out.

Comment: What would happen if you pass a single file `["0.docx"]`, or three files `["0.docx","1.docx","2.docx"]` ?

Comment: @Philippe If I use use it on three files `["0.docx","1.docx","2.docx"]`, then two documents is converted, but i it changes for example, if I run the script once the output will be `(0.pdf, 1.pdf)` and sometimes the output will be `(0.pdf, 2.pdf)`, it changes but only two files are being converted that is for sure.

Comment: @Philippe One document, its working fine, no issues at all. Its getting converted correctly, if you know the issue behind this, please help out on how to properly parallel execute it

Comment: Your code is correct. Does `stdout` or `stderr` for the second "job" offer any clues? Is it possible that the applications itself is not engineered to be run concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is most likely exiting before the conversion of all the files. You likely need to call [`pool.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join) to wait for all files to be converted. Or use the `Pool` as a `contextmanager` (see the example in the linked doc).